# Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I wonder if anyone can help.
I need to write a regular expression that throws away everything apart from the last word if that last word is an alphanumeric (numbers and letters) or a single number or a single letter.

For example

Ground floor Apartment 2

Garden Apartment 1A

Block 2D

Suite 12

Unit C

Basement Flat

General Office

**I would like to remove all words and characters that are not part of the actual number i.e.**

Ground Floor Apartment 2 should become 2

Garden Apartment 1A should become 1A

Block 2D should become 2D

Suite 12 should become 12

Unit C should become C

Basement Flat should become Blank as there is no numbers involved

General Office should become blank

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a positive lookahead which asserts your requirements at the end of the string.

[`(?:\b[A-Za-z]{1}|\d+|(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/PisOW7/1)

**Explanation**

- A non capturing group `(?:`
- A word boundary `\b`
- Match a single letter `[A-Za-z]{1}`
- Or `|`
- One or more digits `\d+`
- Or `|`
- A positive lookahead which asserts that the last word contains a digit `(?=.*\d)`
- Match one or more lower/upper case characters or digits `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`
- Close non capturing group `)`
- The end of the string `$`

Comment: Many Thanks. Perfect. Is there any way to also make an inverse of this. i.e. this matches the end word but we also need to match everything but the end word that matches this pattern so that we can replace everything apart from the last word with a blank string. Thanks again

Comment: You could for example capture 2 groups, the first with what you want to replace and the second with what you already match. Then in your replace you could use only the second group. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/PisOW7/2)

Answer (score -1):

What language are you using? You should be able to get the last word by splitting/exploding the string using spaces, then apply the regex to the last word.

You may want to just handle if the length of the word is 1 to make your regex simpler to understand and troubleshoot. This regex works for any word that is 2 letters or longer.

Here's a regex that should work for that last word. It uses a positive lookahead to ensure one letter and one number are present. https://regex101.com/r/i5R9bq/1/

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-z])[0-9A-z]+
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But it also selects the whole thing if the last letters are say 2A. I need that to stay if there is a number in it. It also doesn't work with say Apartment C.